# How to get all dropdown values in string array in java?

Tags: java, html, arrays, servlets, html-select

I know this is a very basic question but I am not able to track the error

This is my dropdown lists

```
<select name="prodnd" id="prodnd" style="display:none">
                                  <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                                        <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
                                        <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>  
                                </select>
```

I want all these option values in servlet

I tried getParameterValues in servlet

```
String[] prodn = request.getParameterValues("prodnd");
```

but I am only able to get the first option value....

I want all the values

Comment: You might be just selecting the first element?

Comment: Use `Ctrl+click` while choosing options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `multiple` attribute to your `<select>` control

```
<select name="prodnd" id="prodnd" multiple size="3">
```

Then make sure you're selecting multiple values with `CTRL + click`.

---

Don't use a `<select>` control for sending hidden data. Use `<input type="hidden" ... >` as

```
<input type="hidden" name="prodnd" id="prodnd" value="Andorra,Antarctica,Bulgaria" />
```

Then simply split the values back to an array in your Servlet as

```
String[] prodnd = request.getParameter("prodnd").split(",");
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to keep it hidden and at the time of form submission all the values should be sent to the servlet.....I am using this dropdown box for storing values which the user won't be able to see...So the user won't select anything from dropdown...It is just used to send values on the server side.....

Comment: Thanks this did the trick....I would add `.split(',')` method to take all my values in an array.....

Answer (score 0):

`<select>` tag requires individual elements to be selected (either by JS or by user interaction for finding the data it will send.

`<input type="hidden">` may work, but then you will have to convert to your Array or structure as you will receive it as a string.

JSON or serializing the data might also be other options.

I wonder what the use case might be. If you are trying to persist the data across a user's session, then perhaps the `Session attribute` in your servlet is a much better option

Answer (score 0):

Simply use hidden fields instead:

```
<input type='hidden' name='prodnd' value='Andorra'/>
<input type='hidden' name='prodnd' value='Antarctica'/>
<input type='hidden' name='prodnd' value='Bulgaria'/>
```

User won't be able to see it and the values will be sent to the server

If you still want to use drop-down then, mark all options as selected:

```
<select name="prodnd" id="prodnd" style="display:none" multiple>
  <option value="Andorra" selected>Andorra</option>
  <option value="Antarctica" selected>Antarctica</option>
  <option value="Bulgaria" selected>Bulgaria</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use multiple attribute in the select tag

```
<form action="servlet" method="post">
    <select name="prodnd" multiple>
        <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
        <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
        <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: because you didnt get it what is asked.